# Is there any syntaxhighlighter for Excel

Tags: excel, xhtml, syntaxhighlighter

Is there any program or website that could convert an Excel macro code into an html nice looking format.

I used syntaxhighlighter for Java and Java scrtipt.
Is there anything similar fot Excel?

Comment: Syntaxhighlighter has `shBrushVb.js` which should work for VBA macros. Not sure if it handles formulas though.

Comment: I'm guessing it will handle formulas okay and +1 it makes sense to use a tool that you are already comfortable with. However, using another syntax-highlighter shouldn't be too tricky, as they tend to be quite similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether syntaxhighlighter recognises **VBScript**; this is more likely than a specific mention of VBA and almost identical for highlighting purposes. (Just checked, it mentions Visual Basic and VB.NET, so you can continue with syntaxhighlighter - which seems sensible.)

[highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/media/soft/highlight/test.html) mentions VBScript, and has an example, but I haven't used it myself.

In fact, I think most syntax-highlighters will show a reasonable representation of VBA code.

Answer (score 2):

You should check [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which supports several languages (VB included).

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for. He wants to display the code embedded in, most likely, a web-page, so needs a tool that will take the script and wrap it in HTML tags.